# Document field as primary key not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a "document" field that needs to be a primary key and must be unique, but every time I do a POST with the same document it updates the document and doesn't send a BAD_REQUEST

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"document"})})
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, updatable = false)
    @NotBlank @NotNull
    private String document;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

When I try to make a new POST with the same document it just updates what is saved in the database.

**"Hibernate: update client set date=?, name=? where document=?"**

Comment: if document is exist it will update if its not exist it will insert. try to  set document new value when POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Spring Data JPA, when you call `Repository#save`, assumes that you want to update an existing entity when the passed in entity object has the id attribute set. You will have to inject a `EntityManager` in your code and instead call `EntityManager#persist` if you want to make sure that Hibernate tries to do an insert, in which case you'd get a constraint violation exception, just as you expect.